# SQL LEFT OUTER JOIN order by Avg() Reviews

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join

Trying to join to tables together, one has a list of products along with customer budget of cost per click (cpc) and the other table contains the reviews for the products graded 1.0 - 5.0.

My idea is to rank products depending the value of the cpc and how many positive reviews with 5 being the highest.

Some products do not have any reviews so im looking for them to rank lowest.

This is where I am so far, does't seem to perform as expected.

```
   select s.product_name
     , s.product_id store.cpc
     , AVG(r.ratings)
     , r.product_id 
  from store s
     LEFT
     JOIN reviews r
    ON s.product_id = r.product_id 
 WHERE
   MATCH(s.product_name) AGAINST ('xyz' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
   GROUP 
    BY r.product_id 
 ORDER 
    BY s.cpc DESC
     , AVG(r.ratings) DESC
```

I appreciate any help.
Regards

Comment: You are missing a `,` between `store.product_id store.cpc`. You can use `ISNULL` around the `AVG` to give it a value if you don't have any ratings.

Comment: Is there any error you mean?

Comment: Clinomaniac, that was just a typo while writting this post. regards

Comment: No error, im missing products that are not yet reviews and its not ranking by avg().

Comment: @clinomaniac please explain the ISNULL around the AVG, thank you.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Since you have a `LEFT` join, if a product doesn't have reviews, then `reviews.ratings` will be `NULL`. So you can use `ISNULL(AVG(reviews.ratings), 0)` to get a low ratings for those products.

Comment: @clinomaniac i have use COALESCE as ISNULL flags an error in my code but items 4.7 stars are ranking lower 0 star.

Comment: Look at Strawberry's comment and provide that information.

Comment: That group by is invalid. Won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Ive never used sql fiddle before but here is a simplified version of my code... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/564e3b/3

Comment: @shane Made some changes to the where clause and am getting results. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/564e3b/8 What is it that you are expecting and how is this different?

Comment: Yes, but my live code is pretty much the same at the example, but doesnt rank the same. I'v got products with the same cpc but 5 star reviews lower down the rankings? May be its something to to do with the match against? regards

Comment: I have stripped down my code to match the one on sqlfiddle, when my results are displayed, it shows the AVG but the ORDER BY is not working. It orders by 0. Even with the DESC.

Comment: Think i have found the problem, AVG(COALESCE(r.score,0)) is returning as a STRING and not Numeric. I have tried CASE AS DECIMAL but with no luck.

Comment: *CAST AS DECIMAL